# cProfile with imports

Tags: python, profiler, cprofile

I'm currently in the process of learn how to use `cProfile` and I have a few doubts.

I'm currently trying to profile the following script:

```
import time

def fast():
    print("Fast!")

def slow():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Slow!")

def medium():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Medium!")

fast()
slow()
medium()
```

I execute the command `python -m cProfile test_cprofile.py` and I have the following result:

```
Fast!
Slow!
Medium!
     7 function calls in 3.504 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    3.504    3.504 test_cprofile.py:1(<module>)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.501    0.501 test_cprofile.py:10(medium)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test_cprofile.py:3(fast)
    1    0.000    0.000    3.003    3.003 test_cprofile.py:6(slow)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    2    3.504    1.752    3.504    1.752 {time.sleep}
```

However, when I edit the script with a pylab import for example (`import pylab`) on the top, the output of `cProfile` is very large. I tried to limit the number of lines using `python -m cProfile test_cprofile.py | head -n 10` however I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 199, in <module>
main()
File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 192, in main
runctx(code, globs, None, options.outfile, options.sort)
File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 56, in runctx
result = prof.print_stats(sort)
File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 81, in print_stats
pstats.Stats(self).strip_dirs().sort_stats(sort).print_stats()
File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pstats.py", line 360, in print_stats
self.print_line(func)
File "/home/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/pstats.py", line 438, in print_line
print >> self.stream, c.rjust(9),
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Can someone help what is the correct procedure to situations similar with this one, where we have an `import pylab` or another module that generates such high output information on `cProfile`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do the selective profiling like you want by running the `cProfile` module directly from the command line like you're doing.

However, you can do it by modifying the your code to explicitly `import` the module, but you'll have to do everything yourself. Here's how that might be done to your example code:

<sup>(Note: The following code is compatible with both Python 2 and 3.)</sup>

```
from cProfile import Profile
from pstats import Stats
prof = Profile()

prof.disable()  # i.e. don't time imports
import time
prof.enable()  # profiling back on

def fast():
    print("Fast!")

def slow():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Slow!")

def medium():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Medium!")

fast()
slow()
medium()

prof.disable()  # don't profile the generation of stats
prof.dump_stats('mystats.stats')

with open('mystats_output.txt', 'wt') as output:
    stats = Stats('mystats.stats', stream=output)
    stats.sort_stats('cumulative', 'time')
    stats.print_stats()
```

`mystats_output.txt` file's contents afterwards:

```
Sun Aug 02 16:55:38 2015    mystats.stats

         6 function calls in 3.522 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time, internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    3.522    1.761    3.522    1.761 {time.sleep}
        1    0.000    0.000    3.007    3.007 cprofile-with-imports.py:15(slow)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.515    0.515 cprofile-with-imports.py:19(medium)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 cprofile-with-imports.py:12(fast)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

**Update:**

You can make enabling the profiling a little easier by deriving your own `Profile` class with a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-context-manager) method to automate things. Instead of adding a method with a name like `enable_profiling()` to do this, I've implemented it so that you can just call the class instance in a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement. Profiling will automatically be turned off whenever the context controlled by the `with` statement is exited.

Here's the class:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from cProfile import Profile
from pstats import Stats

class Profiler(Profile):
    """ Custom Profile class with a __call__() context manager method to
        enable profiling.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.disable()  # Profiling initially off.

    @contextmanager
    def __call__(self):
        self.enable()
        yield  # Execute code to be profiled.
        self.disable()
```

Using it instead of a stock `Profile` object would look something like this:

```
profiler = Profiler()  # Create class instance.

import time  # Import won't be profiled since profiling is initially off.

with profiler():  # Call instance to enable profiling.
    def fast():
        print("Fast!")

    def slow():
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Slow!")

    def medium():
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Medium!")

    fast()
    slow()
    medium()

profiler.dump_stats('mystats.stats')  # Stats output generation won't be profiled.

with open('mystats_output.txt', 'wt') as output:
    stats = Stats('mystats.stats', stream=output)
    stats.strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumulative', 'time')
    stats.print_stats()

# etc...
```

Since it's a `Profile` subclass, all the base class' methods, such as `dump_stats()` are all still available for use as shown.

You could, of course, take it further and add e.g. a method to generate the stats and format them in some customized way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The fact that outputs a text file maybe be an advantage in case I'm try to do some graphical stuff with it.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually the default `stream` is `sys.stdout`. My motivation for setting it up to write to a file was for use with gui-based programs. A hands-on approach like this not only allows you to fine-tune what section(s) of your code are profiled, the `pstats.Stats` instance also has a number of useful methods that provide a fair amount of control over what's output and how — check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-pstats) for details.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your script slightly, then it'll be much easier to profile the script without also profiling your imports.

#### test_cprofiler.py

```
import time
import pylab

def fast():
    print("Fast!")

def slow():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Slow!")

def medium():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Medium!")

def main():
    fast()
    slow()
    medium()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### profiler.py

```
import cProfile

import test_cprofiler

cProfile.run("test_cprofiler.main()")
```

Run as:

```
python profiler.py
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Fast!
Slow!
Medium!
         8 function calls in 3.498 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.498    3.498 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    2.998    2.998 run.py:11(slow)
        1    0.000    0.000    3.498    3.498 run.py:15(main)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 run.py:4(fast)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.500    0.500 run.py:7(medium)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    3.498    1.749    3.498    1.749 {time.sleep}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems a elegant way to overcome my issue.